# Nodejs knex connect to mysql error pool destroy

Tags: mysql, node.js, knex.js

I use nodejs connect to mysql by knex. It's my code:

```
var logger = configlog.getLogger("dao-movies");
var configConnection = {
    client: 'mysql',
    connection: {
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        user: 'root',
        password: '',
        database: 'mobile_movie',
        port: 1234
    }
};
var knex = require("knex")(configConnection);

var getUser = function () {
    knex("tbl_user").select()
        .then(function (rows) {
            logger.info(rows);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            logger.error("Error select tbl_user: " + error);
        });
}
```

But it's not working.

This is the error:[image]